# How to correctly pass a v-model down to a Quasar q-input base component?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) to build my Vue app and I want to create a [base component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Base-component-names-strongly-recommended) (a.k.a. presentational, dumb, or pure component) using `q-input`.

I have a created a SFC named `VInput.vue` as my base component, it looks like this:

```
<template>
  <q-input
    outlined
    class="q-mb-md"
    hide-bottom-space
  />
</template>
```

Then I created a SFC named `TestForm.vue` that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <q-form>
    <v-input label="Email" v-model="email" />
  </q-form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import VInput from './VInput.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';
const email = ref('john@example.com');
</script>
```

The `label="Email" v-model="email"` parts are passed down to my `VInput.vue` base component and correctly rendered on the page.

But there is a typescript error on `q-input` of the `VInput.vue` base component because `q-input` requires a v-model:

```
`Type '{ outlined: true; class: string; hideBottomSpace: true; "hide-bottom-space": boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & QInputProps'.`
`Property 'modelValue' is missing in type '{ outlined: true; class: string; hideBottomSpace: true; "hide-bottom-space": boolean; }' but required in type 'QInputProps'.ts(2322)`.
```

So how do I code the `VInput.vue` base component without knowing the v-model value head of time?

I have come up with the below solution, which seems to work because I think the v-model passed down is overiding the base component v-model.

But I wanted to ask to make sure I wasn't screwing something up.

Is this the correct way of doing things? It seems hacky.

```
<template>
  <q-input v-model="inputText" outlined class="q-mb-md" hide-bottom-space />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const inputText = '';
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a couple of solutions:

### Solution 1

It involves splitting the `v-model` into it seperate parts (`:model-value` and `@update:model-value`, and then passing in the text value as a prop.

Base component `VInput.vue`:

```html
    <template>
      <q-input
        outlined
        class="q-mb-md"
        hide-bottom-space
        :model-value="text"
        @update:model-value="(value) => emit('update:text', value)"
      />
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    defineProps({
      text: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
      },
    });
    const emit = defineEmits(['update:text']);
    </script>
```

### Solution 2

Extracting the prop and using `toRef` on it.

```html
    <template>
      <q-input outlined class="q-mb-md" hide-bottom-space v-model="textProp" />
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { toRef } from 'vue';
    const props = defineProps({
      text: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
    });
    const textProp = toRef(props, 'text');
    </script>
```

Comment: Solution 1 works well; I couldn't get Solution 2 to work; I get: "Set operation on key "text" failed: target is readonly" (I have `v-model="textProp"` as you suggest). This is with Vue 3.2.x; not using TypeScript but I don't think that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Docs Vue3 here https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html explain how this works, so this solution worked for me - parent:

```
<VInput v-model="someText" />
```

VInput.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    nice and shiny input:
    <q-input outlined class="q-mb-md" @update:modelValue="(newValue) => $emit('update:modelValue', newValue)" hide-bottom-space v-model="textProp" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { toRef } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps(['modelValue'])
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
const textProp = toRef(props, 'modelValue');
</script>
```